# Sling @Inject NullPointerError, When @Reference Successful

Tags: java, osgi, aem, inject, sling

When trying to `@Inject` (javax.inject.Inject) to inject `MyConfigurationService` within `@SlingServlet MyServlet` leads to a `NullPointerError` anytime any operations are attempted on `myConfigurationService` within an AEM OSGi container using Maven `org.apache.felix.maven-scr-plugin` as part of the build process.

**Service Implementation:**

```
@Service({MyConfigurationService.class})
@Component(immediate = true, metatype = true, label = "My Configuration Service")
public class MyConfigurationServiceImpl implements MyConfigurationService {
    @Property(unbounded = PropertyUnbounded.DEFAULT, label = "API URL", description = "API URL")
    private static final String API_URL = "apiurl";

    private String apiUrl;

    @Activate
    protected void activate(Map<String, Object> properties) {
        this.apiUrl = PropertiesUtil.toString(properties.get(API_URL), "");
    }
}
```

**Servlet:**

```
@SlingServlet(paths = "/bin/myServlet", methods = "POST", metatype = true)
public class MyServlet extends org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingAllMethodsServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyServlet.class);

    @Inject
    MyConfigurationService myConfigurationService;

    @Override
    protected void doPost(SlingHttpServletRequest request, SlingHttpServletResponse response) throws ServerException, IOException {
        // any attempts to use myConfigurationService results in NPE
    }
}
```

However using `@Reference` (org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Reference) in place of `@Inject` successfully injects the service and is usable within the `@SlingServlet` methods such as `doPost`:

```
@Reference
MyConfigurationService myConfigurationService;
```

Why does `@Inject` fail to inject the service into the `@SlingServlet` when `@Reference` works?

Thank you for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are confusing the sling models @Inject with SCR annotations used by the maven SCR plugin.

The maven SCR plugin defines annotations to be processed at `build time` those are defined here: http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-maven-scr-plugin/scr-annotations.html
All those annotations are under the package `org.apache.felix.scr.annotations`

The @Reference annotation can only be used with @Component, @service, @SlingServlte or any other SCR class annotation that defines an OSGI component.

The `javax.inject.Inject` annotation is generic and is used by many frameworks for dependency injection. In AEM or Sling's case, it only means something inside a Sling Model (a class annotated by `org.apache.sling.models.annotations.Model`), read more about @Inject and other annotations that can be used in a Sling Model here: https://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/models.html#basic-usage

Comment: So `@Inject` is something really only used in @Model annotated elements, while `@Reference` would be used within `@Service`, `@Component` or similar annotated elements to effectively accomplish dependency injection?